# how to calculate the reproduction number $R_0$ in stochastic model

Tags: stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, stochastic-calculus, mathematical-modeling, stochastic-differential-equations

There are several specific ways to calculate the reproduction number $R_0$ for the deterministic model I extracted it properly, but in the stochastic model I found a difference in how to extract it.
For example in this [article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.researchsquare.com/article/rs-1924420/v1.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiNpNqYxZX7AhUKPewKHZHgBuYQFnoECBYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1PnmOhFRJYLJLi6Rfm6hyU),
By taking the infected class as:
$$
dI=\beta \tau S(t) I(t) +\beta \tau k I(t) V(t)-(\sigma+\mu+\epsilon) I(t) +\beta_3IdW_3
$$
Using Itô's lemma for twice differentiable function
$$f(t, I(t)) =ln(t, I(t))$$
After simple calculations we get:
$$
d(t, I(t)) =[\beta\tau S(t) +\beta \tau k V(t)-\frac{1}{2} \beta^2_3-(\sigma+\mu+\epsilon)] dt+\beta_3dW_3(t)
$$
Now, he choice that:
$$
F=\beta\tau S(t) +\beta \tau k V(t)-\frac{1}{2} \beta^2_3
$$
And
$$
V=-(\sigma+\mu+\epsilon) 
$$
F : the rate of appearance of new infected in the compartment I.

V : the transfer rate of individuals entering and leaving the compartment I.

But in other models I noticed that the term $\frac{1}{2}\beta^2_3$ appears in $V$ not $F$ as:
$$
F=\beta\tau S(t) +\beta \tau k V(t) 
$$
And
$$
V=-(\sigma+\mu+\epsilon)-\frac{1}{2}\beta^2_3 
$$
Here I do not understand which of the two options is correct.
Can someone direct me to which one?

Comment: Assuming the general math community knows what you mean by $F$ and $V$ is not a good idea. Additionally, you still haven't shown these choices actually result in different $R_0$.

Comment: I edited it, thanks for noticing